How to make my django views.py read excel sheet and display a blank cell, not "nan"
I am working on a project using django and plotly. It reads from an excel sheet and displays the data accordingly. Everything works except I have a child survey column that is only populated with some parent surveys. Because of that, the cells without a child survey are displaying 'nan' instead of just being empty. this is my function in views.py:
def survey_status_view(request):
    # Fetch data for all CLINs and calculate necessary values
    clin_data = []

    # Get all unique combinations of CLIN and child survey
    unique_clins = SurveyData.objects.values('clin', 'survey_child').distinct()

    for clin in unique_clins:
        clin_id = clin['clin']
        child_survey = clin['survey_child']

        # Check if the child_survey is 'None' (the string), and handle it appropriately
        if child_survey == 'None':
            child_survey = ''  # Replace 'None' with an empty string

        # Filter by both clin and child_survey
        survey_data = SurveyData.objects.filter(clin=clin_id, survey_child=child_survey)

        # Total units for the current CLIN and child survey
        total_units = survey_data.first().units if survey_data.exists() else 0

        # Count redeemed units based on non-null redemption dates
        redeemed_count = survey_data.filter(redemption_date__isnull=False).count()

        # Calculate funds for this CLIN and child survey
        total_funds = total_units * survey_data.first().denomination if total_units > 0 else 0
        spent_funds = redeemed_count * survey_data.first().denomination if redeemed_count > 0 else 0
        remaining_funds = total_funds - spent_funds

        # Append results for this CLIN and child survey
        clin_data.append({
            'clin': clin_id,
            'survey': survey_data.first().survey if survey_data.exists() else '',
            'child_survey': child_survey,  # Use the updated child_survey with empty string if it's 'None'
            'status': survey_data.first().status if survey_data.exists() else '',
            'launch_date': survey_data.first().launch_date if survey_data.exists() else '',
            'expiration_date': survey_data.first().expiration_date if survey_data.exists() else '',
            'total_units': total_units,
            'redeemed_count': redeemed_count,
            'spent_funds': spent_funds,
            'total_funds': total_funds,
            'remaining_funds': remaining_funds,
            'redemption_rate': (redeemed_count / total_units * 100) if total_units > 0 else 0,
        })

    # Log the results for debugging
    for data in clin_data:
        print(f"CLIN: {data['clin']}, Child Survey: {data['child_survey']}, Total Units: {data['total_units']}, "
              f"Redeemed Count: {data['redeemed_count']}, Spent Funds: {data['spent_funds']}, "
              f"Remaining Funds: {data['remaining_funds']}")

    # Render the data in the template
    return render(request, 'surveyStatus.html', {'clin_data': clin_data})

and this is the html associated, but I don't think that's where the problem lies:
{% load humanize %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Survey Status</title>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #002060;
            color: white;
        }
        .active-row {
            background-color: #e2f3d7;
        }
        .inactive-row {
            background-color: #fde9d9;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Survey Status</h1>
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'virtual_delivery' %}">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>SELECT</th>
                    <th>CLIN</th>
                    <th>Survey</th>
                    <th>Child Survey</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Launch Date</th>
                    <th>Expiration Date</th>
                    <th>Redemption Rate</th>
                    <th>Total Funds</th>
                    <th>Spent Funds</th>
                    <th>Remaining Funds</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for clin in clin_data %}
                <tr class="{% if clin.status == 'Active' %}active-row{% elif clin.status == 'Pre-Launch' or clin.status == 'Inactive' %}inactive-row{% endif %}">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="clin" value="{{ clin.clin }}"></td>
                    <td>{{ clin.clin }}</td>
                    <td>{{ clin.survey }}</td>
                    <td>{{ clin.child_survey }}</td>
                    <td>{{ clin.status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ clin.launch_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ clin.expiration_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ clin.redemption_rate|floatformat:1}}%</td>
                    <td>${{ clin.total_funds|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td> <!-- Show total funds with thousand separator -->
                    <td>${{ clin.spent_funds|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>  <!-- Show spent funds with thousand separator -->
                    <td>${{ clin.remaining_funds|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>  <!-- Show remaining funds with thousand separator -->
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">View Charts</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

I've tried chatgpt and this is my next source. please someone help a brother out.

can you try this in html?
<td>{{ clin.child_survey|default_if_none:"" }}</td>

or can you try this on views?
unique_clins = SurveyData.objects.annotate(
    child_survey_filled=Coalesce('survey_child', Value(''))
).values('clin', 'child_survey_filled').distinct()

In this code, the Coalesce function fills the None values ​​in the database with empty strings. Thus, there will be None in the data coming from the database.
